# Adding a new property dynamically to model (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and can't seem to add a new property, here's my code including a comment section that shows the output which does not return the new attribute I added called Url.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Exercice extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'exercices';
    protected $connection = 'DB_V2';
    protected $appends = ['Url'];


    public function getUrlAttribute() {
        return 'custom';
    }

    /*
    $exercise = App\Exercice::where("idExercice", 1)->get();
    dd($exercise);

          #attributes: array:15 [▼
        "idExercice" => 1
        "image1" => "160_A.jpg"
        "image2" => "a.jpg"
        "thumb1" => "v.jpg"
        "thumb2" => "c.jpg"
        "video" => "fliqz|077fzc4f478142cea8a73e586617f8a\r\n"
        "draw1" => ""
        "draw2" => ""
        "drawthumb1" => ""
        "drawthumb2" => ""
        "licno" => 1000
        "idusager" => 0
        "code_exercice" => "XAMP160"
        "shared" => "Y"
        "rank" => 99999999
      ]
      */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is not going to show up in a `dd()` of the object itself, because the attribute doesn't actually exist in the `$attributes` property.

If you `dd()` the array or json output, you should see your value:

```
$exercise = App\Exercice::where("idExercice", 1)->get();
dd($exercise->toArray());
```